# MTurk HITs created Through Java API are not showing on Manage Tab on UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am creating HITs on MTurk Sandbox using JAVA API. I am able to create HITs and also work on it by searching through worker UI. But those hits are not showing up in the "Manage" tab of the requester UI.

Answer (score 5):

So as to interact with my own MTurk tasks I have developed a rudimentary management console to monitor, review, manage, and download data from API-launched tasks.

The management console is entirely JavaScript based and runs locally in your web browser. It replicates most of the basic functionality removed with the Manage HITs individually module in the December 2017 changes. You will need your API keys to use the tool but these are not stored nor transmitted to myself or any third-party.

You can download a copy from GitHub: https://github.com/jtjacques/mturk-manage/archive/master.zip

Please see the included README for comprehensive information about the tool, available on the GitHub project page https://github.com/jtjacques/mturk-manage

Answer (score 2):

The "Manage" tab in the MTurk Requester Website is for managing Batches created with the MTurk Requester Website (using the Create) tab. If you need/want to view HITs that you create with the API, you can use the [ListHITs API method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ListHITsOperation.html) either with the API directly (using your Java code) or using the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI).

Here's a blog explaining how to do this with the AWS CLI: 
https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-managing-mturk-hits-with-the-aws-command-line-interface-56eaabb7fd4c

The blog shows how to use aws-shell, which is a more interactive shell that sits atop the AWS CLI. It has autocomplete and shows you inline "man" pages on each command. I personally prefer this.

The CLI and aws-shell will also let you write filters and formatters for results. So you can do things like this:

```
aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus}' --endpoint-url https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --max-results 5
```

This calls [ListHITs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ListHITsOperation.html), on the Sandbox (--endpoint), getting only 5 results (--max-results), formats the output as a table instead of the default JSON (--output) and filters that JSON for the HITs object (HITs[]) pulling down only the fields HITId, Title, and Status while also setting titles for those fields as "1. HITId", "2. Title", and "3. Status".

There used to be a link in the MTurk Requester Website for a GUI to manage HITs individually which would show HITs from the API, but it was deprecated this month. There's a brief thread on it here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=267769&tstart=0

Comment: Is there an inbuilt capability to download results from API or through CLI? This is available for HITs created through Requester UI. I want to have an excel sheet similar to that provided by UI for HITs created through API, and then use it to approve/reject work. Is it also possible through CLI, or do I have to write custom code for this?

Comment: So does this mean that all hits created via the API and resulting data are invisible in the MTurk requester (sandbox) interface? You can only access them via the API? This seems weirdly inconvenient ...