# HITs created with Boto3 do not appear under "Manage Batches" in sandbox

Tags: boto3, mechanicalturk

As the title says, I have created some HITS with Boto3 with the following code (obviously redacted):

```
import boto3

# this is the sandbox server
mturk = boto3.client(
    'mturk',
    aws_access_key_id="REDACTED",
    aws_secret_access_key="REDACTED",
    region_name='us-east-1',
    endpoint_url='https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
)



# creates a hit - note that it accesses a file for the xml-formatted question
def create_test_hit():
    question = open('path/to/mlearnBoto_question.xml', mode='r').read()

    new_hit = mturk.create_hit(
        Title='Title',
        Description='Task description',
        Keywords='language, psychology, experiment',
        Reward='2',
        MaxAssignments=1,
        LifetimeInSeconds=75600,
        AssignmentDurationInSeconds=10800,
        AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds=604800,
        Question=question
    )

create_test_hit()
```

However, the batches do not appear in the "Manage" tab at the link https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/manage (everything is 0).

Just to be sure, I run

```
pprint(mturk.list_hits())
```

And indeed my HIT was there.

Am I not understanding something? Shouldn't I be able to see the HITs I created in Boto in the "manage" tab? If not, where can I see them?

Comment: HITs created via the API do not display in the batch user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/jtjacques/mturk-manage

> The management console is entirely JavaScript based and runs locally
>   in your web browser. It replicates most of the basic functionality
>   removed with the Manage HITs individually module in the December 2017
>   changes. You will need your API keys to use the tool but these are not
>   stored nor transmitted to myself or any third-party.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48404999/5511061