# submitted HIT in mturk workersandbox, but can't view result in requester sandbox

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I keep running into mysterious issues when testing my sample MTurk task in the sandbox environment. In the requester environment, I create a task by copy/pasting HTML/JS code into the "Source" text box under Create > Edit Project > (2) Design Layout.

I'm able to preview the task on that page, and it appears to work correctly. I can also publish the HIT in the RequesterSandbox, which lands me on this page: [RequesterSandbox > Manage > Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwl5c.jpg)

I can also log into the WorkerSandbox, find my HIT, and complete it. However, when I press submit, I'm redirected to a page that says "Loading next HIT...," and then to another page, which says ["Sorry, we couldn't find that page.
Strange...the page you were looking for is not here. Let's go home and try again"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be1fb.jpg)

Going BACK to the RequesterSandbox, there is no evidence that the HIT was submitted at all, and I can't find the HIT results. I suspect that it isn't being submitted properly in the WorkerSandbox, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the HTML/javascript code for my sample task:

```js
// extract url parameters
var queryDict = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
  queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]
})

// use extracted url parameters to populate form
$("#endForm").attr("action",queryDict["host"]);
$("#assignmentID").val(queryDict["assignmentId"]);
$("workerId").val(queryDict["workerId"]);
$("#hitId").val(queryDict["hitId"]); 

// reveal submit button after radio button is selected 
$('#question_buttons').change(function(){
  var btnResponse = $("input[name='theseButtons']:checked").val();
  if (btnResponse == "thisOne" || btnResponse == "thatOne") {
    $("#endTask").removeClass("hidden");
  }
})

// submit response 
$("submitButton").click(function() {
      $("#endForm").submit();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>MTurk HIT Test</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" id="endForm" method="post" name="endForm">
 <input id="data" name="data" type="hidden" value="" /> 
 <input id="assignmentId" name="assignmentId" type="hidden" value="{{ assignment_id }}" /> 
 <input id="workerId" name="workerId" type="hidden" value="{{ workerId }}" /> 
 <input id="hitId" name="hitId" type="hidden" value="{{ hitId }}" />

 <div class="container">
  <h3>Write something:</h3>
  <br />
  <textarea cols="50" name="answer" rows="2"></textarea>
 </div>

 <div class="container" id="question_text">
  <h3>Select one of these options:</h3>
 </div>

 <div class="container" id="question_buttons">
  <div class="radio-inline">
   <label><input name="theseButtons" type="radio" value="thisOne" />this one</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio-inline"><label>
   <input name="theseButtons" type="radio" value="thatOne" />that one</label>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container hidden" id="endTask">
  <h3>Submit form by clicking the button below:</h3>
  <br />
  <input id="submitButton" name="submitButton" type="submit" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The results created on sandbox worker UI would not show on the sandbox requester page.

You can also see the answer through this URL:
[MTurk HITs created Through Java API are not showing on Manage Tab on UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730479/mturk-hits-created-through-java-api-are-not-showing-on-manage-tab-on-ui)
There is a console tool to manage the Mturk HIT on sandbox.