# MTurk API: Unable to see my created HIT on dashboard

Tags: python, boto3, mechanicalturk

I am using the tutorial given [here](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-a-beginners-guide-to-crowdsourcing-ml-training-data-with-python-and-mturk-d8df4bdf2977). It says HIT is created but when I go here `https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/` I don't find the project I created. Though individual worker URL does return HIT web interface.

The reason I want to know that I want not only to automate HIT creation but publishing of batch as well. My code is given below:

```
MTURK_SANDBOX = 'https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
    mturk = boto3.client('mturk',
                         aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                         aws_secret_access_key=SECRET,
                         region_name='us-east-1',
                         endpoint_url=MTURK_SANDBOX
                         )

    print("I have $" + mturk.get_account_balance()['AvailableBalance'] + " in my Sandbox account")

    question = open('questions.xml', encoding='utf8').read()
    new_hit = mturk.create_hit(
        Title='Is this Tweet happy, angry, excited, scared, annoyed or upset?',
        Description='Read this tweet and type out one word to describe the emotion of the person posting it: happy, angry, scared, annoyed or upset',
        Keywords='text, quick, labeling',
        Reward='0.15',
        MaxAssignments=1,
        LifetimeInSeconds=172800,
        AssignmentDurationInSeconds=600,
        AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds=14400,
        Question=question,
    )
    print("A new HIT has been created. You can preview it here:")
    print("https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=" + new_hit['HIT']['HITGroupId'])
    print("HITID = " + new_hit['HIT']['HITId'] + " (Use to Get Results)")
```

Answer (score 7):

Mechanical Turk currently doesn't provide a way to publish a batch of HITs through the API. You must call `CreateHIT` for each of of them individually.

Also, HITs created through the API aren't visible in the UI. You can see these through the API. You can also use the AWS command line shell to manage them, since it uses the API, too.

Sources:

1. https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-managing-mturk-hits-with-the-aws-command-line-interface-56eaabb7fd4c
2. [MTurk HITs created Through Java API are not showing on Manage Tab on UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730479/mturk-hits-created-through-java-api-are-not-showing-on-manage-tab-on-ui)

Comment: so I have to collect emails from 1000 URLs , I have to create 1000 HITs by calling `create_hit`? A couple of question, how to send paramterized data? 2nd, how to submit it so others can start collecting data?

Comment: yes, it would be multiple create_hit calls. you could have a worker do more than one URL in the same HIT, of course. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITLayoutArticle.html for ways to separate layout from paramaterized data.