# New HIT is not shown on the dashboard with HITs

Tags: python, mechanicalturk

When I' creating new HIT [programmatically](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateHITOperation.html) with this python script (got it from this [tutorial](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-a-beginners-guide-to-crowdsourcing-ml-training-data-with-python-and-mturk-d8df4bdf2977)):

```py
import boto3
import os

MTURK_SANDBOX = 'https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

mturk = boto3.client('mturk',
    aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
    aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_KEY'],
    region_name='us-east-1',
    endpoint_url=MTURK_SANDBOX
)

with open('template.xml', 'r') as f:
    question = f.read()

new_hit = mturk.create_hit(
    Title = 'Choose either this page xxx or yyy',
    Description = 'Choose the correct category for the document',
    Keywords = 'document, classification',
    Reward = '0.15',
    MaxAssignments = 1,
    LifetimeInSeconds = 172800,
    AssignmentDurationInSeconds = 600,
    AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds = 14400,
    Question = question,
)

print('\n'.join(["A new HIT has been created. You can preview it here:",
    "https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId={0}".format(new_hit['HIT']['HITGroupId']),
    "HITID = {0} (Use to Get Results)".format(new_hit['HIT']['HITId'])]))
```

`template.xml` looks like:

```xml
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
  <HTMLContent><![CDATA[
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>
<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">
    <crowd-classifier
        categories="['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']"
        header="Does this page contain xxx or yyy?"
        name="category">
        <classification-target>
            <iframe src="${document_url}" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>
        </classification-target>
        <short-instructions>Please choose the correct category for the document</short-instructions>
        <full-instructions header="Document Classification Instructions">
            <p>Some instructions...</p>
        </full-instructions>
    </crowd-classifier>
</crowd-form>
    </body>
    </html>
    ]]></HTMLContent>
  <FrameHeight>0</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
```

It successfully creates new HIT and prints HIT_ID to console output, but I can't see it under my projects in requester sandbox account at https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/create/projects to upload CSV batch file for `document_url` property. But I can see it with `list_hits` API method.

I'm using IAM account with `mechanical turk full access` permission, which I created under primary linked to MTurk account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HITs created through the MTurk Requester API won't populate the Web-based MTurk Requester portal. This is a known limitation (it's been like this for as long as I can remember).

E.g. see [MTurk HITs created Through Java API are not showing on Manage Tab on UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730479/mturk-hits-created-through-java-api-are-not-showing-on-manage-tab-on-ui)

Comment: Thanks, I've got similar answer on AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=913682